# Incompatible function pointer

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating an instance of class B in a method of class A (which is a `QMainWindow`) with `B instanceB;` and then call a method of B with `B.method()` and pass it the function pointer of a method of A.

Now the compiler says `argument of type "void (A::*)()" is incompatible with parameter of type "void (*)()"`. How do I resolve this if possible?

Code:

```
void A::method1_of_A(void)
{
    B instanceB;
    B.methodB(method2_of_A); // this is where the compiler complains
}
```

Comment: If you wrote a function that accepts a `void (*)()` argument, you should rewrite it. If somebody else wrote it, complain to them loudly. Such function is *unusable*. It should accept a `std::function<void()>` argument instead.

Comment: I wrote it myself. So `methodB` should be `void B::methodB(std::function<void()>)` instead of `void B::methodB(void (*function)())`? Because that's what I took from a "function pointers in C++" article. Can you elaborate on the difference?

Comment: Generally, can you point me to the right source to learn about all this?

Comment: Which article is that? `void (*)()` can *only* access global variables. It is fundamentally incompatible with any member function pointer that has an implicit `this` parameter.

Comment: @RadaD Your basic mistake is that `method2_of_A` is not a function, it's a method. One solution is to change `methodB` to accept a pointer to a method, e.g. `void methodB(void (A::*function)())` Without knowing the context this may not be correct for you. But that's the basic mistake, methods cannot be assigned to function pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Parameter `void (*)()` can only accept a free function.

If you have parameter `std::function<void()>`, it can call any callable, so you can adapt your member function with a lambda capturing the object and pass that

```
B.methodB([&a](){ a.method2_of_A(); })
```

or binding the member function to the object (including <functional>)

```
B.methodB(std::bind(&A::method2_of_A, a))
```

Of course, clearest intent is in @John's comment, where you know a member function of A is expected:

```
void methodB(void (A::*function)()) { (this->*function)(); }
```

Comment: I think you meant `void (*)()` can only accept a free function.

Comment: @john Correct, copy error. fixed.

Comment: @john And I nicked your comment.